# How to get the name of a sub by it's handles in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, handles

I want to find the a the name of a specific sub that I only know it's handles.

example:

```
Function GetSub(Handle As EventHandler) As Object
    'Help!!!
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   TextBox1.Text = "Hello world!"
End Sub
```

is there a way? Thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?525533-Retrieving-the-EventHandler-for-any-Event-by-code Possibly relevant.

Comment: How and when is GetSub called? How are you getting the handle to pass to getsub?

Comment: I know this isn't what you're looking for but may help lead you in the right direction. You can get the name of the calling sub from doing a stack trace. Maybe you can get the handle as well. MsgBox((New System.Diagnostics.StackTrace).GetFrame(1).GetMethod.Name)

Comment: Why do you want to do this in the first place?  It seems a very strange thing to do.  It may be that there's a better option.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I want to my program generate a new button when needed that will have all the properties of the original even it's EVENTS. Can you help me find a better way?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to be able to duplicate any arbitrary `Button` or is this a specific set of `Button` controls that are always going to have the same `Click` event handler?

Comment: Exactly! But sometimes I will need to do the same with other controls, not only Buttons. Can you help?